# Car wrapping: use of varnish on matte vinyle?

Tags: vinyl, varnish

I was reading this post [Glossy black logo on matte black background](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97809/glossy-black-logo-on-matte-black-background) which is the exact effect I am seeking for an eccentric car wrap.

Given the difficulty to find a professional able to produce that kind of finish (it apparently requires expensive machines), I was thinking about making a stencil with the desired shapes, applying a varnish by myself on the vinyl surface through the stencil and being done with it.

But: it is a -racing and fun- car and has to face weather conditions and wash.

What would be the best way to make that varnish resistant to time and abuse on this vinyl support?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Please explain to help me improving

Comment: No reason to improve. You had a technical problem and many members here are more interested in graphic content problems. Fortunately at least one of us happened to know something about the practical side of your case and wrote an usable answer. Probably you would get more of them in another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular car lacquer in rattle can. Or plastidip top gloss coat.
Or you can order cutout letters from gloss vinyl and apply them on matte wrap.

Most company car that are wrapped in custom foil are racing and for fun ones. Because they are company ones :)

Comment: I will take the cutout pattern way. Much faster. Thanks!